# NDB Jinja2 best way to access KeyProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

i've this model

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    password = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()


class Offer(ndb.Model):
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
    cut = ndb.StringProperty()
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Call(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    called_by = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
    offers = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Offer, repeated=True)
    status = ndb.StringProperty(choices=['OPEN', 'CLOSED'], default="OPEN")
    dt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

i've this view

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        calls_open = Call.query(Call.status == "OPEN").fetch()
        calls_past = Call.query(Call.status == "CLOSED").fetch()
        template_values = dict(open=calls_open, past=calls_past)
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

and this small test tempalte

```
{% for call in open %}
    <b>{{call.name}} {{call.called_by.get().name}}</b>
    {% endfor %}
```

now, **with the `get()` it works perfectly.**

my question is: **is this correct?
is there a better way to do it?** 
personally i found it strange to `get()` the values in the template and i would prefer to fetch it inside the view.

my idea was to:

- create a new list `res_open_calls=[]`
- for all the call in calls_open call the to_dict() `dict_call = call.to_dict()`
- then assign to the dict_call  `dict_call['team'] = call.team.get().to_dict()`
- add the object to the list `res_open_calls.append(dict_call)`
- then return this just generated list.

this is the gist i wrote ( for a modified code) https://gist.github.com/esseti/0dc0f774e1155ac63797#file-call_offers_calls

it seems more clean but a bit more expensive (a second list has to be generated). is there something better/clever to do?

Comment: You're not showing us the `Call` entity but rather `Team` and `Offer` only.  I do agree w/your preference to have actual logic in the view, not the template, but can't help w/the info you've given, so pls edit your Q to give complete info, thanks!

Comment: BTW, quite possibly the best solution (depending on the `Call` entity) may be a computed property or instance method in the model -- that's somewhat of an `ndb` style quirk, but it's often my personal preference:-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli my bad, add the Model and also the GIST of the code i wrote.

Comment: I'm still very confused.  Now you say `called_by` is a `StringProperty`, so `call.called_by` is a string and calling `get` on it should crash and burn, yet you claim it works -- therefore the models you actually use must be very different; and in the text you mention `call.team` which doesn't exist in the model you show -- I'm going to answer based on guesses on how exactly you're trying to sabotage our ability to help, but not being a mindreader makes this hit-and-miss at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is clearly showing code very different from the one they're using: they show `called_by` as a `StringProperty` so calling `get` on it should crash, they talk about a `call.team` that doesn't exist in the code they show... anyway, I'm trying to guess what they actually have, because I find the underlying idea is important.

The OP, IMHO, is correct to be uncomfortable about having DB operations right in a Jinjia2 template, which would be best limited to presentation-level issues.  I'll assume (guess!) that part of the `Call` model is:

```
class Call(ndb.Model):
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
```

and the relevant part of the Jinja2, currently working for the OP, is:

```
{{{{call.team.get().name}}
```

A better structure might then be:

```
class Call(ndb.Model):
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
    @property
    def team_name(self):
        return self.team.get().name
```

and in the template just `{{call.teamname}}`.

This still performs the DB operation during template expansion, but it does so on the Python code side of things, rather than the Jinja2 side of things -- better than embodying so much detail about the model's data architecture in a template that should focus on presentation only.

Alternatively, if a `Call` instance is `.put` rarely and displayed often, and its `team` does not change `name`, one could, so to speak, `cache` the value in a `ComputedProperty`:

```
class Call(ndb.Model):
    team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
    def _team_name(self):
        return self.team.get().name
    team_name = ComputedProperty(self._team_name)
```

However, this latter choice is inferior (as it involves more storage space, does not save execution time, and complicates actual interactions with the datastore) **unless** some queries for `Call` entities also need to query on `team_name` (in which latter case it would be a must).

If one did chose this alternative, the Jinjia2 template would **still** use `{{call.teamname}}`: this hints at why it's best to use in templates only logic strictly connected to presentation -- it leaves more degrees of freedom for implementing attributes and properties on the Python code side of things, without needing to change the templates.  "Separation of concerns" is an excellent principle in programming.

The snippet posted elsewhere suggests a higher degree of complication, where `Call` is indeed as shown but then of course there is no `call.team` as shown repeatedly in the question -- rather, a double indirection via `call.offers` and each `offer.team`.  This makes sense in terms of entity-relationship modeling but can be heavy-going to implement in the essentially "normalized" terms the snippet suggests in any NoSQL database, including GAE's datastore.

If teams don't change names, and calls don't change their list of offers, it might show better performance to **denormalize** the model (storing in `Call` the technically redundant information that, in the snippet, is fetched by running through the double indirection) -- e.g by **structured properties**, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured , to **embed** copies of the `Offer` objects in `Call` entities, and a copy of the `Team` object (or even just the team's name) in the `Offer` entity.

Like all de-normalizing, this can take a few extra bytes per entity in the datastore, but nevertheless could amply pay for it by minimizing the number of datastore accesses needed at `fetch` time, depending on the pattern of accesses to the various entities and properties.

However, by now we're straying far away from the question, which is about what to put in the template, what on the Python side.  Optimizing datastore patterns is a separate issue well worth of Qs of its own.

Summarizing my stance on the latter, core issue of Python code vs template as residence for logic: data-access logic should be on the Python code side, ideally embedded in `Model` classes (using `property` for just-in-time access, possibly all the way to denormalization at entity-building or perhaps at entity-finalization time); Jinjia2 templates (or any other kind of pure presentation layer) should only have logic directly needed for presentation, not for data access (nor business logic either of course).

Comment: My bad for the code, i put the wrong one. This answer is amazing. Where can i find more info about the better strategy to create the db? because i used this strategy quite often and to me it's not still clear when to use a separated table, repeated key, or repeated structuredProperty for the relationships.

Comment: @EsseTi, I've always found Dan Sanderson's work to be instructive; his blog is at http://ae-book.appspot.com/ and the latest edition of his book (now two separate ones for GAE Python and GAE Java) available in Early Release (and print editions due in April) as the blog mentions.  (Disclaimer: I may be biased as he's a colleague and we both write for the same publisher, but I don't know him personally).